# Uploading image from Android to Apache Server using AsyncTask not working on all Android devices

Tags: android, image, android-asynctask, upload, multipart

**Hello, Stack Overflow Community.**

Ya'll are my last hope:

We have an Android App under development...

Users are given the option to upload an image from Cam or locally from Gallery.

In both cases, we can see the image preview/thumbnail is getting displayed in the App correctly upon user selecting the image (or taking the Cam snap).

In other words, I believe we can confirm that the image is getting captured / selected / set successfully.

As soon as the user selects the File Image, the "Uploading..." progress bar is displayed:

[image]

For Image Files smaller than ~250k, it works!!

However... **here's the weerd part:**

For Image Files greater than ~250k, the progress bar freezes / hangs, and then (eventually - after a few minutes) returns on fail to upload.

**It's not a server-side issue (I assume) because:**

- This works 100% on some Android devices;
- This works 100% on other iOS devices;

**It's not a Android Version issue, per se:**

- Works on Asus Tablet using Android 7.0;
- Does not work on MGT Mobile Phone Android 7.0;

...i.e., two devices - each using Android 7.0 -- one works -- one does not.

**NETWORK NOTES:**

- We can see that during times when the file fails to upload, we don't see any successful connection to the server.

**SMALL FILES WORK!!!**

- Again, even on the devices where this issue exists... small files "work" -- i.e., files that are smaller than 250k will get successfully uploaded, while Files greater than 1MB will simply fail to even connect to the server.

*So bizarre.*

CODE:

```js
private class KYCAppLogoAPIAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> {
        private int imageSequence = imageNo;
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        private Context context;
        private Exception exception;
        private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

        private KYCAppLogoAPIAsyncTask(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

            String whitelabel_app_name = "";// always empty  // getUserData("whitelabel_app_name");
            if (!whitelabel_app_name.isEmpty()) {
                SITE_TITLE = whitelabel_app_name;
                return "LoadWebView";
            }
            try {
                return KYCAppLogoAPICall();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                return jsonMessage("An error occurred! Please try again later.");
            }
        }

        private String KYCAppLogoAPICall(){
            HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
            HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
            String responseString = null;

            String SERVER_PATH  = "http://" + API_DOMAIN + "/link_gateway/get_member_emailaddress.gate";
            SERVER_PATH = "http://" + API_DOMAIN + "/link_gateway/intelitruth_test_POST.gate";
            Log.d("url", SERVER_PATH);

            try {
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(SERVER_PATH);
                MultipartEntityBuilder multipartEntityBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();

                // Extra parameters if you want to pass to server
                multipartEntityBuilder.addPart("whitelabel_business_account_hash", new StringBody(whitelabel_business_account_hash, ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN));
                multipartEntityBuilder.addPart("member_hash", new StringBody(getUserData("member_hash"), ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN));
                multipartEntityBuilder.addPart("account_hash", new StringBody(getUserHash(), ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN));
                multipartEntityBuilder.addPart("PAYYAP_version", new StringBody(getUserData("versionName"), ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN));
                multipartEntityBuilder.addPart("PAYYAP_device_type", new StringBody(getUserData("deviceType"), ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN));

                httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

                int statusCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                if (statusCode == 200) {
                    // Server response
                    responseString = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
                } else {
                    responseString = "Error occurred! Http Status Code: "
                            + statusCode;
                }
            }
//            catch (UnsupportedEncodingException | ClientProtocolException e) {
//                e.printStackTrace();
//                Log.e("UPLOAD_ERROR", e.getMessage());
//                this.exception = e;
//                String android_patch_redirect_url = getUserData("android_patch_redirect_url");
//                if(!android_patch_redirect_url.isEmpty()){
//                    openWebPage(android_patch_redirect_url);
//                }
//            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                String android_patch_redirect_url = getUserData("android_patch_redirect_url");
                if(!android_patch_redirect_url.isEmpty()){
                    openWebPage(android_patch_redirect_url);
                }
            }

            return responseString;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {


        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String jsonStr) {

            Log.d("TAG", "Response from server: " + jsonStr);
            showAlert(jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                if (jsonStr.equals("LoadWebView")) {
                    loadWebview();
                } else {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                        JSONObject logo = jsonObj.getJSONObject("logo_url");
                        String whitelabel_app_name = logo.getString("whitelabel_app_name");
                        if (!whitelabel_app_name.isEmpty()) SITE_TITLE = whitelabel_app_name;
                        String icon_square = logo.getString("icon_square");
                        String banner_rectangle = logo.getString("banner_rectangle");
                        String form_flow = jsonObj.getString("form_flow");

                        String help_url = "";
                        String privacy_policy_url = "";
                        JSONObject hot_menu = jsonObj.getJSONObject("hot_menu");
                        if (!hot_menu.isNull("whitelabel_FAQ_url")) {
                            help_url = hot_menu.getString("whitelabel_FAQ_url");
                        }
                        if (!hot_menu.isNull("whitelabel_privacy_policy_url")) {
                            privacy_policy_url = hot_menu.getString("whitelabel_privacy_policy_url");
                        }
                        String android_patch_redirect_url = jsonObj.getString("android_patch_redirect_url");
                        ;

                        if (form_flow.equals("single_page")) {
                            saveUserHash("");
                        }

                        saveUserData("whitelabel_app_name", SITE_TITLE);
                        saveUserData("icon_square", icon_square);
                        saveUserData("banner_rectangle", banner_rectangle);
                        saveUserData("form_flow", form_flow);
                        saveUserData("help_url", help_url);
                        saveUserData("privacy_policy_url", privacy_policy_url);
                        saveUserData("android_patch_redirect_url", android_patch_redirect_url);
                        Log.d("TAG", "form_flow: " + form_flow);

                        loadWebview();

                    } catch (final JSONException e) {
                        Log.d("TAG", "error: " + e.getMessage());

                        saveUserData("whitelabel_app_name", "");
                        saveUserData("icon_square", "");
                        saveUserData("banner_rectangle", "");
                        saveUserData("form_flow", "logical_step");

                        loadWebview();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {

        }
    }
```

LOG CAT:

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Ryjz5wcR3H/

Any thoughts suggestions at all will be incredibly greatly appreciated.

Thank you all.

Comment: You can try OKHTTP lib for image upload.
Refer link for multi part http://www.zoftino.com/android-okhttp-example

Comment: OK, will try OKHTTP lib.  Thank you.

Comment: Try to use Retrofit+Rxjava,forget httpclient and AsyncTask

Comment: OK. will try Retrofit+Rxjava.  Thank you.  Do you have a link to these resources, by chance?